# Binary to Base64 (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, encoding, delphi-2010, base64

How can I get content of an `exe` file and convert it into `Base64` encoding ?

**Edit**

I use `D2010` and I want to know how is it possible exactly ?

- `open an exe file`
- `convert its content into base64`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In Delphi 2009/2010/XE there is unit `EncdDecd.pas` (`Soap.EncdDecd.pas` for Delphi XE2) containing the functions `EncodeBase64` and `DecodeBase64`. You can load the exe file into a memorystream and then call EncodeBase64.

```
function EncodeFile(const FileName: string): AnsiString;
var
  stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    stream.LoadFromFile(Filename);
    result := EncodeBase64(stream.Memory, stream.Size);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I use D2010 and i want to know how is it possible exactly ? `1-open an exe file` `2-convert its content into base64` ?

Comment: Did you look to see if D2010 includes the `EncdDecd` unit? @Uwe's code shows you exactly how to use it.

Comment: The unit is also available in D2010. I edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: For those using ancient Delphi versions, equivalent functions are found somewhere in the Indy's Mime Encoding stuff.

Comment: @Warren: specifically, Indy's IdCoderMIME unit contains base64-enabled classes.

Comment: There's also the CryptBinaryToString function from Crypt32.dll (WinXP+) for those with older Delphi version.

Comment: You mean, you want to know how to save an AnsiString to a file? I guess that counts as a separate question...

Comment: Be aware of the fact that EncodeBase64 from the EncdDecd.pas unit will insert 2 AnsiChar's (#$D#$A == CRLF) every 75 base64 encoded chars. You have no way of telling it not to do it. At least the java version has a boolean to control if you want this additional "intelligence". Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer just saved my life for sending binary files via JSON :D

Comment: In later versions of Delphi (not sure where it started):

uses
  System.NetEncoding;
TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(Stream.Memory, Stream.Size)

Comment: FYI, the TNetEncoding mentioned by DaveNottage was added in XE7, as I just found out. Use EncdDecd with earlier versions.

Answer (score 9):

In ancient Delphi versions, you can use `synapse` ([link here](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/start))

Just put `synacode.pas` in your uses e call EncodeBase64/EncodeBase64.

Cheers

Comment: Synapse doesn't come with any version of Windows. Maybe you meant indy?

Comment: @Marco van de Voort. No, I mean synapse. Look at the link.

Comment: My bad, I meant that synapse doesn't come packaged with Delphi, indy does.

Answer (score 0):

As also mentioned in the comments, since Delphi XE8 you can use the `System.NetEncoding.TNetEncoding.Base64` class property.
It also returns a `string` instead of an `AnsiString`:

```delphi
function TryEncodeFile(const AFileName: string; out ABase64string: string): Boolean;
var
  MemStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MemStream.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
    ABase64string :=
      TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(MemStream.Memory, MemStream.Size);
    Result := True;
  finally
    MemStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```