# How to encode file of any type into base64 string and then decode it into file again using Lazarus/Delphi?

Tags: delphi, serialization, base64, freepascal, lazarus

Can you tell me how can I do that? Is there any Freepascal unit that can do this for me? I need that so my program can store binary data in it's XML-based fileformat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [binary-to-base64-delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795263/binary-to-base64-delphi/5795440#5795440)

Comment: @Uwe Is that unit available in FPC?

Comment: @David, as I don't have Lazarus I don't know. That's why I wrote _possible_.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`base64`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/base64/index.html) unit and its two classes, `TBase64EncodingStream` and `TBase64DecodingStream`.

Here is a [simple example](http://fpc-docs.gorilla3d.com/built-in-units/base64/tbase64encodingstream):

```
program demo;

uses Classes, base64;

var
  DecodedStream: TStringStream;
  EncodedStream: TStringStream;
  Encoder: TBase64EncodingStream;
  Output: string;
begin
  DecodedStream := TStringStream.Create('Hello World!');
  EncodedStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  Encoder       := TBase64EncodingStream.Create(EncodedStream);
  Encoder.CopyFrom(DecodedStream, DecodedStream.Size);

  Output := EncodedStream.DataString;
  { Outputs 'SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh' }
  WriteLn(Output);

  DecodedStream.Free;
  EncodedStream.Free;
  Encoder.Free;
end.
```

And, in the [opposite direction](http://fpc-docs.gorilla3d.com/built-in-units/base64/tbase64decodingstream):

```
program demo;

uses Classes, base64;

var
  DecodedStream: TStringStream;
  EncodedStream: TStringStream;
  Decoder: TBase64DecodingStream;
  Output: string;
begin
  EncodedStream := TStringStream.Create('SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh');
  DecodedStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  Decoder       := TBase64DecodingStream.Create(EncodedStream);
  DecodedStream.CopyFrom(Decoder, Decoder.Size);

  Output := DecodedStream.DataString;
  { Outputs 'Hello World!' }
  WriteLn(Output);

  DecodedStream.Free;
  EncodedStream.Free;
  Decoder.Free;
end.
```

or the shorthands [encodestringbase64](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/base64/encodestringbase64.html) and [decodestringbase64](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/base64/decodestringbase64.html) (2.4.4+) for non stream based usage:

```
Uses Base64;
var 
   s : AnsiString;
Begin
  s:=EncodeStringBase64('Hello world!');
  Writeln('Encoded : ',s);
  s:=DecodeStringBase64(s);
  Writeln('Decoded again : ',s);    
end.
```

Comment: Yes, it will work with any form of stream. That's really the point of making it stream based.

Comment: Btw Since 2.4.4 there are also a couple of plain helper functions in that unit that do the stream wrapping for ease of use.

Comment: @marco thanks. I think that is worth an answer if you would be so good.

Comment: A superb and clear answer! I was tring to find this info myself and stumbled across this. Thanks for including the non-streamed method, too, as that is what I needed to use.