# Validating Base64 input with Free Pascal and DecodeStringBase64

Tags: base64, freepascal, lazarus

I know there are dozens of questions about this already, in various forms. My question is slightly more direct though.

Using Free Pascal and the s:=DecodeStringBase64(s); function, is there anyway to validate if the decoded string that is passed as s is actually decoded from proper Base64 input data in the first place to avoid decoded garbage?

The best I have done is used a reg exp to identify potential Base64 data ([from the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475074/regex-to-parse-or-validate-base64-data)). I then check if it is divisible by 4 using mod. If it is divisible by 4, I pass it to DecodeStringBase64. However, I am still getting lots of false positives and returned data that has 'decoded' but was clearly not Base64 in the first place, despite matching the reg exp. For example "WindowsXP=" matches the expression but is not Base64 encoded data.

Equally, the name 'Ted' encodes as VGVk which doesn't even have the usual '=' padding (which can help to flag it as a footer) but it still a potential Base64 fragment that I'd like to find and decode.

In PHP, there is [base64_decode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556345/detect-base64-encoding-in-php) for which a true parameter can be passed to help with validation.

AFAIK, Free Pascal does not have this with [DecodeStringBase64](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/base64/decodestringbase64.html) and I need some way of validating.

Other useful replies around the subject of decoding and encoding, if the reader happens to be looking for it as I was yesterday, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242580/how-to-encode-file-of-any-type-into-base64-string-and-then-decode-it-into-file-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, there is no 100% working validation for Base64 encoded strings.

The `=` sign in [`Base64`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt) encoded string is not significant, it is for [`padding`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) and so it doesn't always need to be there (encoded string just have to be multiple 4 in length). You can only check if the string length is multiple of 4, check for valid characters from the Base64 alphabet (see [`Page 5, Table 1`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt)) and verify, if there is not more than two `=` padding sign chars at the end of the input string. Here's a code, that can verify, if the passed string can be a valid Base64 encoded string (nothing more you can do, anyway):

```
function CanBeValidBase64EncodedString(const AValue: string): Boolean;
const
  Base64Alphabet = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9', '+', '/'];
var
  I: Integer;
  ValLen: Integer;
begin
  ValLen := Length(AValue);
  Result := (ValLen > 0) and (ValLen mod 4 = 0);
  if Result then
  begin
    while (AValue[ValLen] = '=') and (ValLen > Length(AValue) - 2) do
      Dec(ValLen);
    for I := ValLen downto 1 do
      if not (AValue[I] in Base64Alphabet) then
      begin
        Result := False;
        Break;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Afaik there are also requirements about the = chars at the end.

Comment: @Marco, if there's more than 2 of `=` chars at the end of the encoded string, you should ignore them, but I guess `DecodeStringBase64` doesn't do that... I'll add also the check, if the `=` char count at the end doesn't exceed 2 chars. Thanks for pointing this out! Anyway, when the `=` char is found before the end of the string, it should be also treated as invalid...

Comment: My Reg Exp is : Base64StringPattern.Expression := '([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)';      So, the strings passed to the function you wrote TLama will, in theory, only have one or two = signs at the end of them anyway. Though I take the point that for implementation into FPC (As Marco writes below) a check throughout the string will be necessary. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll update the code to reflect also the `=` sign rules. There can't be more than two of them at the end of the string and there can't be any inside of the string. I'll be right back...

Comment: I've added the validation for more than two `=` signs at the end of the input string and removed the `=` sign from the Base64 alphabet.

Comment: TLama...just gave your imropvoed code a whirl and it rejects a Base64 value that it previously decoded (i.e. my program doesn't process it so the function must be returning false). The value is d2lyZXNoYXJrLXN0dWRlbnRzOm5ldHdvcms= and it should decode to 'wireshark-students:network' (or similar). As I don't need it due to my reg exp, I have just taken that bit out for now but I thought I'd let you know. Maybe it something I doing wrong, but all I did was add those two lines and the var and it now doesn't process it.

Comment: I've just tried the `d2lyZXNoYXJrLXN0dWRlbnRzOm5ldHdvcms=` and it gives me a True as a result. Don't you have e.g. line break in that string (#13#10) ?

Comment: My source data is fed into a StringList and I pass that to the regular expression using a for i := 0 to Sl.Count -1 do So I assume the answer is yes, because SL's have end of line markers I think? Do you think that is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the next version (2.6.2), the DecodeStringBase64 will have an extra boolean parameter that invokes strict mode. (which was already available in the "stream" version).

If there is a validation error an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thankyou Marco. I'm always relieved when a question I ask turns out to be appropriate and helpful to the overall development of FPC\Lazarus.