# Encode base64 and Decode base64 using delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, encoding, base64, decoding, delphi-2007

I have to encode an array of bytes to a base64 string (and decode this string) on an old Delphi 2007.
How could I do?

**Further Informations:**

I've tried synapse (As suggested here [Binary to Base64 (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795263/binary-to-base64-delphi)).

Comment: Base64 is a standard encoding regardless of language or version. Which means there's something wrong with either how it's being encoded or decoded. Can we see your code for both?

Comment: You can use Indy try the `TIdDecoderMIME` class.

Comment: And `TIdEncoderMIME`

Comment: The EncdDecd.pas is not in $(DELPHI)\Source\Internet path?

Comment: @Jerry Dodge: You're right, trying with a small example, synapse lib functions seem to work as expected. There should be something wrong in my code (Or a particular case), I'll check this.

Comment: @Mohamad: As I know, it has been introduced in delphi 2010

Comment: @Hwau: I have use this unit in Delphi 7.

Comment: @Mohamad: You're right! Sorry, so I can use this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indy ships with Delphi, and has `TIdEncoderMIME` and `TIdDecoderMIME` classes for handling base64.  For example:

```
uses
  ..., IdCoder, IdCoderMIME;

var
  Bytes: TIdBytes;
  Base64String: String;
begin
  //...
  Bytes := ...; // array of bytes
  //...
  Base64String := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(Bytes);
  //...
  Bytes := TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeBytes(Base64String);
  //...
end;
```

There are also methods for encoding/decoding `String` and `TStream` data as well.

**Update**: alternatively, if your version does not have the `class` methods shown above:

```
// TBytesStream was added in D2009, so define it manually for D2007

uses
  ..., IdCoder, IdCoderMIME
  {$IF RTLVersion < 20)
  , RTLConsts
  {$IFEND}
  ;

{$IF RTLVersion < 20)
type
  TBytesStream = class(TMemoryStream)
  private
    FBytes: TBytes;
  protected
    function Realloc(var NewCapacity: Longint): Pointer; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const ABytes: TBytes); overload;
    property Bytes: TBytes read FBytes;
  end;

constructor TBytesStream.Create(const ABytes: TBytes);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FBytes := ABytes;
  SetPointer(Pointer(FBytes), Length(FBytes));
  FCapacity := FSize;
end;

const
  MemoryDelta = $2000; // Must be a power of 2

function TBytesStream.Realloc(var NewCapacity: Integer): Pointer;
begin
  if (NewCapacity > 0) and (NewCapacity <> FSize) then
    NewCapacity := (NewCapacity + (MemoryDelta - 1)) and not (MemoryDelta - 1);
  Result := Pointer(FBytes);
  if NewCapacity <> FCapacity then
  begin
    SetLength(FBytes, NewCapacity);
    Result := Pointer(FBytes);
    if NewCapacity = 0 then
      Exit;
    if Result = nil then raise EStreamError.CreateRes(@SMemoryStreamError);
  end;
end;
{$IFEND}

var
  Bytes: TBytes;
  BStrm: TBytesStream;
  Encoder: TIdEncoderMIME;
  Decoder: TIdDecoderMIME;
  Base64String: String;
begin
  //...
  Bytes := ...; // array of bytes
  //...
  BStrm := TBytesStream.Create(Bytes);
  try
    Encoder := TIdEncoderMIME.Create;
    try
      Base64String := Encoder.Encode(BStrm);
    finally
      Encoder.Free;
    end;
  finally
    BStrm.Free;
  end;
  //...
  BStrm := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    Decoder := TIdDecoderMIME.Create;
    try
      Decoder.DecodeBegin(BStrm);
      Decoder.Decode(Base64String);
      Decoder.DecodeEnd;
    finally
      Decoder.Free;
    end;
    Bytes := BStrm.Bytes;
  finally
    BStrm.Free;
  end;
  //...
end;
```

Comment: It works good on further delphi version! Thanks for your suggestion and sample, I'll check this on Delphi 2007 as soon as possible, but I suppose it also works on old ide.

Comment: @Hwau: you can upgrade Indy to the latest version, even on older Delphi's

Comment: Unfortunately, EncodeBytes and DecodeBytes functions are undeclared using Delphi2007. I would prefer to don't upgrade indy manually, is there another way?

Comment: @Hwau: You will have to look in D2007's `IdCoder` unit and see what functions are actually available in that version. Worse case, the `class` methods might not be available, so try instantiating `TIdEncoderMIME`/`TIdDecoderMIME` objects and use their non-`class` methods instead. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I'm sorry for long silence, TBytesStream seems to be undefined in Delphi-2007, how else could I load bytes array into stream?

Comment: `TBytesStream` was added in D2009. I have updated my answer to include an implementation for D2007.  Or, you could simply copy the bytes into a standard `TMemoryStream`.

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to what you state in the question, the `EncdDecd` unit is included in Delphi 2007. You can simply use that.

Answer (score 4):

David Heffernan responded very well!

Add in your uses the class "EncdDecd", it will have the procedures:

```
function DecodeString (const Input: string): string;
function DecodeBase64 (const Input: string): TBytes;
```

Testing with https://www.base64encode.org/

The String "Working" in both Delphi and the site resulted in: "V29ya2luZw =="

```
ShowMessage ('Working =' + EncodeString ('Working'));
ShowMessage ('Working =' + DecodeString ('V29ya2luZw =='));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here goes EncodeToBase64:

```
uses
classes, sysutils;

function EncodeToBase64(var Buffer: TBytes): Longint;
const
  EncodingTable: PChar = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
var
  WriteBuf: array[0..3] of Byte;
  Buf: array[0..2] of Byte;
  Dest: TMemoryStream;
  i, j, Count: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;

  Count := Length(Buffer);
  j := Count div 3;

  if j > 0 then
  begin
    Dest:= TMemoryStream.Create();  
    try
      Dest.Position := 0;
      for i := 0 to j - 1  do
      begin
        Move(Buffer[i * 3], Buf[0], 3); 
        WriteBuf[0] := Ord(EncodingTable[Buf[0] shr 2]);
        WriteBuf[1] := Ord(EncodingTable[(Buf[0] and 3) shl 4 or (Buf[1] shr 4)]);
        WriteBuf[2] := Ord(EncodingTable[(Buf[1] and 15) shl 2 or (Buf[2] shr 6)]);
        WriteBuf[3] := Ord(EncodingTable[Buf[2] and 63]);  
        Dest.Write(WriteBuf, 4);  
        Inc(Result, 4);
        Dec(Count, 3);    
      end;          

      if Count in [1, 2] then  
      begin           
        Move(Buffer[i * 3], Buf[0], Count);
        WriteBuf[0] := Ord(EncodingTable[Buf[0] shr 2]);
        WriteBuf[1] := Ord(EncodingTable[(Buf[0] and 3) shl 4 or (Buf[1] shr 4)]); 
        if Count = 1 then
          WriteBuf[2] := Ord('=')
        else                                           
          WriteBuf[2] := Ord(EncodingTable[(Buf[1] and 15) shl 2 or (Buf[2] shr 6)]);
        WriteBuf[3] := Ord('='); 
        Dest.Write(WriteBuf, 4);  
        Inc(Result, 4);
        Dec(Count, Count);
      end;

      if Result > 0 then
      begin
        SetLength(Buffer, Result);
        Dest.Position := 0;
        Dest.Read(Buffer[0], Result);   
      end;  
    finally
      Dest.Free;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

And this should work without any special units or components.

Answer (score 1):

For OLDER versions of Delphi (before of Delphi XE7), use:

```
uses 
Soap.EncdDecd
```

```
procedure DecodeFile(const Base64: AnsiString; const FileName: string);
var
  BStream: TBytesStream;
begin
  BStream := TBytesStream.Create(DecodeBase64(Base64));
  try
    BStream.SaveToFile(Filename);
  finally
    BStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For NEWS versions of Delphi, use:

```
uses
System.NetEncoding;
```

```
procedure DecodeFile(const Base64: String; const FileName: string);
var
  BStream: TBytesStream;
begin
  BStream:= TBytesStream.Create(TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(Base64));
  try
    BStream.SaveToFile(Filename);
  finally
    BStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```