# delphi Send a file as byte array to a Rest service

Tags: arrays, rest, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin

I want to send image data as `TBytes` to a Rest service using `TRestRequest`, but I could not find a way to pass a `TBytes` to the `TRestRequest.AddBody()` method, or any other method.

```
POST http://myserver:1111//Openxxx/RecxxxLxxxPxxxx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/json
Host: myserver:1111
Content-Length: 28892
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,219,0,132,0,9,
...
...
...
130,130,252,168,127,164,63,164,41,109,204,245,62,106,51,135,12,146,63,255,217]
```

Comment: Wouldn't be simpler to pass it encoded as Base64 so you just pass an string ?. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795263/binary-to-base64-delphi

Comment: I'm trying to call an existing webservice, which is used by others (written in C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem like below:

```
function BytesToStr(abytes: tbytes): string;
var
  abyte: byte;
begin
   for abyte in abytes do
   begin
      Result := result + IntToStr(abyte) + ',';
   end;
   Result := '[' + Copy(Result, 1, Length(Result) - 1) + ']';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   ABytes: TBytes;
begin
   ABytes := TFile.ReadAllBytes('images.jpg');
   RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('body', BytesToStr(ABytes), pkREQUESTBODY, [], ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
   RESTRequest1.Execute;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

[`TRESTRequest.AddBody()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddBody) has an overload that accepts a `TStream` as input. You can wrap your `TBytes` into a `TStream` using the [`TBytesStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TBytesStream) class.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ABytes: TBytes;
  AStream: TBytesStream;
begin
  ABytes := ...;
  try
    AStream := TBytesStream.Create(ABytes);
    RESTRequest1.AddBody(AStream, ctIMAGE_JPEG); 
    RESTRequest1.Execute;
  finally
    AStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, use [`TRESTRequestParameterList.AddItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameterList.AddItem) instead, which has an overload for `TBytes`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ABytes: TBytes;
begin
  ABytes := ...
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('body', ABytes, pkGETorPOST, [poDoNotEncode], ctIMAGE_JPEG);
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
end;
```

That being said, I find `TRESTClient` to be overly complex and buggy/limiting.  More times than not, Indy's `TIdHTTP` is easier to use, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ABytes: TBytes;
  AStream: TBytesStream;
begin
  ABytes := ...;
  try
    AStream := TBytesStream.Create(ABytes);
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://myserver:1111//Openxxx/RecxxxLxxxPxxxx', AStream);
  finally
    AStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'image/jpeg';
  IdHTTP1.Post('http://myserver:1111//Openxxx/RecxxxLxxxPxxxx', 'image.jpg');
end;
```

Comment: I tried like below but no change.

`code`var
   ABytes: TBytes;
   AStream: TBytesStream;
begin
   ABytes := TFile.ReadAllBytes('images.jpg');
   AStream := TBytesStream.Create(ABytes);
   RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
   RESTRequest1.AddBody(AStream);// ByteArrayToString(ABytes));
   RESTRequest1.Execute;
end;`code`

Comment: It creates a message like:  <br/>

`POST http://s-lywms:2364//OpenAlpr/RecognizeLicensePlates HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,
Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0.8
User-Agent: Embarcadero RESTClient/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: s-lywms:2364`

Comment: I can't answer that without digging into the REST client's source code. But why are you reading a file into a `TBytes` wrapped in a `TStream` instead of just using a `TFileStream` directly? `var AStream: TFileStream; begin AStream := TFileStream.Create('images.jpg', fmOpenRead); RESTRequest1.ClearBody; RESTRequest1.AddBody(AStream); RESTRequest1.Execute; AStream.Free; end;`

Comment: Hi Remmy first i want to thank you but your solution creates an empty REST request. There is no body data. And i want to remind that I am not supplier/provider of this service, I am trying to write my client and provider waits a byte array (i think it means TBytes).

`POST http://s-lywms:2364//OpenAlpr/RecognizeLicensePlates HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,
Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0.8
User-Agent: Embarcadero RESTClient/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: s-lywms:2364

`

Comment: @RemyLebeau  How use RESTRequest1.AddBody(...  if have more than one parameter rg. first parameter is image name, second  image blob memory stream?