# Using Google cloud platform to convert speech to text

Tags: json, delphi, audio

I am trying to create app for speech to text.
With the following `JSON` code I get results back:

```
        {
"config": {
            "encoding":"FLAC",
            "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
            "languageCode": "en-US",
            "enableWordTimeOffsets": false 
             }, 
    "audio": {"uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"  }
    }
```

I am using `EncdDecd` unit for  `EncodeFile` function. The  problem is when I am trying to pass my audio file as `Base64` string with the following code:

```
        {
"config": {
            "encoding":"FLAC",
            "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
            "languageCode": "en-US",
            "enableWordTimeOffsets": false 
             }, 
    "audio": {
"content":"'+EncodeFile(myaudio_flac_filename)+'"  }
    }
```

What is the function to convert a `WAV` file to `Base64` string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this answer: [Binary to Base64 (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795263/binary-to-base64-delphi/5795440#5795440)

If that doesn't work for some reason, let us know what version of Delphi you are on and what errors you are running into.

Comment: well yes i try this it does convert it The problem is that is difernet convertion than the convertion of https://www.base64encode.org/ who does it right.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how it is different? I created a test file, 'test.bin' that contains 4 random bytes, 2A 78 BF 9D. Using the Delphi code above in Seattle, the output was "Kni/nQ==". I then went to base64encode.org, and imported the test.bin file. The result was the same, "Kni/nQ==". Feel free to give more information like details of your testing, code, version of Delphi, etc.

Comment: I used the Encodefile function in Soap.EncdDecd,pas and its the same encoding i dont know why but in wav was complety diferent .Problem solved thanks.